# Cannot change xtick labels on boxplot with matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have this script that refuses to print the xtick labels that I set it to. Currently it is printing the numbers 1-6 as the labels.

```
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Algorithms accuracy comparison for %s data'%(scales[0]))
    #ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    pyplot.boxplot(results[:len(models)])
    nticks = 6
    labs = ['LR', 'SVM', 'CART', 'LR', 'SVM', 'CART']
    ax.set_xticklabels(labs)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nticks))
    pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Current code should give you an error: `NameError: name 'ax' is not defined`. Please update the code by uncommenting the line `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)` and add more information about the plot. May be commenting the line `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nticks))` helps?

Comment: Thanks, I solved it! will update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the correct solution

```
# boxplot algorithm comparison
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Algorithms accuracy comparison for %s data'%(scales[0]))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    pyplot.boxplot(results[:len(models)])
    ax.set_xticklabels(['LR','LDA','KNN','CART','NB','SVM'])
    ax.set_ylabel('Accuracy')
    ax.set_xlabel('Models')
    pyplot.show()
```